# Installing XMLBeans on Windows 7 for NetBeans

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I am having issues with installing XMLBean on Windows 7 for NetBeans.

The instructions for Windows machine is here: http://puu.sh/4SyGR/b3c170def4.png

It seems that these instructions are slightly out of date - probably meant for an earlier version of Windows (XP maybe?).

Does anyone have any experience with installing this on Windows 7? I apologize if this is the wrong forum to ask.

Comment: My advice is to never, ever use XML beans.  It plagued our codebase for years.  It's awful.

Comment: What do you use for parsing XML in Java?